# Unable to load FragmentActivity from Main Activity android

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity

I want to call Fragment Activity from an initial Activity..

The app consists of two classes..
And all I want to do is when I click the btn1(Button) from MainActivity, 
it should show the Google Map V2..(I don't want to call it as an fragment activity that belongs to MainActivity,,)

1. MainActivity.java (Activity)
2. MapView.java (FragmentActivity)

However, it shows the following errors

```
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mgrs.converter.pro/com.mgrs.converter.pro.MapView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at com.mgrs.converter.pro.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:65)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-20 17:44:51.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1615):     ... 11 more
```

------MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mLocMan = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mProvider = mLocMan.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
        LocationListener mListener = new Geocoord();



    //Button 0
    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ....    
    }
    }); //ends button0

    //Button 1
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.performClick();



            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapView.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }//ends onClick 

        });

    }//ends onCreate


}//ends Activity
```

------MapView.java

```
public class MapView extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    //Variables vari;
    Converter converter = new Converter();



    //initial values for marker
    LocationManager mLocMan;
    String mProvider;
      //current position
      double lon = converter.getLongitude();
      double lat = converter.getLatitude();
      //site#1
      double lon1 = converter.getfinalLon();
      double lat1 = converter.getfinalLat();
      //site#2
      double lon2 = converter.getinitLon();
      double lat2 = converter.getinitLat();       



      //google Maps LatLng() method
      LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lon);
      LatLng position1 = new LatLng(lat1, lon1);
      LatLng position2 = new LatLng(lat2, lon2);

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mapview);          

      mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
      mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();

      //add marker
      //mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("current")).showInfoWindow();
      mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.site1)).position(position1).title("Site#1")).showInfoWindow();
      mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.site2)).position(position2).title("Sitee#2")).showInfoWindow();

      //
      mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position1, 10));
     }//ends onCreate
}//ends MapView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setMapType()` after you get a reference to it. [Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

```
// Get a handle to the Map Fragment
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mGoogleMap` before initializing it on:

```
mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();
```

You should swap these lines.